# svnserve vs xinetd + svnserve

Tags: svn, svnserve, xinetd

What would be the best solution considering, scalability/load and security, svnserve + xinetd or standalone svnserver? Thank you!

Comment: How many concurrent uses do you have to serve ?

Comment: It would be aprox. up to 100 concurrent uses.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget there is always svn over ssh, and `mod_dav_svn`, both widely deployed, and highly reliable.

Comment: It is on the internal network, so I don't think that ssh is needed. mod_dav_Svn is already in use. What I'm curios of if there are some advantages (beside the ones I can think of) of running svnserve with xinetd instead of running it standalone. Basically I'm making a small cleanup and I want to get rid of the xinetd daemon if there is no need for it.

Comment: I second the desire to drop `xinetd` if you don't need it. I've had no problems running `svnserve` over internal and external networks.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can think of as a benefit of doing it with xinetd is with regards to multiple repositories.

If you are looking to have one svnserve serving up multiple repositories, you'd need to use the -r switch, and load up svnserve.

However adding a new repository tree would require a restart of the entire svnserve process, possibly interrupting current users.

If you use xinetd it will automatically be picked up the next time the system is quite (and you don't have to wait around for it to happen).

At the moment that's the only advantage I can see to using xinetd.